# spring autowired classes are null in jersey rest

Tags: spring, annotations, jersey, autowired

I'm new to Spring and Jersey. I have web application which consists of spring servlet and jersey rest servlet. When I try use spring's autowire annotation in jersey rest servlet, I get nullpointerexception on those object. Others jersey based methods works fine.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>My Application</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>


<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet1</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/JerseyServlet1-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>
            com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
        </param-name>
    <param-value>pl.mypack.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseyServlet1</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And JerseyServlet1-servlet.xml file:

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.mypack" />

    <bean id="jspViewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"></property>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages"></property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties"></bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
        p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
        p:password="${jdbc.password}"></bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contactDAO" class="pl.mypack.dao.ContactDAOImpl"></bean>

    <bean id="contactService" class="pl.mypack.service.ContactServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="pl.mypack.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="RestService" class="pl.mypack.rest.RestServiceImpl"></bean>
    <bean id="userDAO" class="pl.mypack.dao.UserEntityDAOImpl"></bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

And Java class:

package pl.mypack.rest;

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import pl.mypack.dao.ContactDAO;
import pl.mypack.dao.UserEntityDAO;
import pl.mypack.domain.UserEntity;

@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @Autowired
    private ContactDAO contactDAO;

    @Autowired
    private UserEntityDAO userDAO;

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }


        @GET
    @Path("/getcontacts")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        public String getAllContactList(@QueryParam("login") String login, @QueryParam("pass") String password) { 
            UserEntity usr = userDAO.findByLoginData(login, password);
            if(usr != null)
            {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                return gson.toJson(contactDAO.getLoggedUserContacts(usr.getId()));
            }
        return null;  
        }

}
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Post your dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: `@Autowired` annotated fields cannot be `null` if managed by Spring. You must be missing the jersey-spring integration libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are loading dispatcher-servlet context 2 times.
There are two possibilities for why beans are not being autowired:
1) If your service and data access beans(like you mentioned ContactDAO, UserEntityDAO etc.,) are in separate config xml, say config.xml, then mention in web.xml as:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Remove the reference of >/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml from this contextConfigLocation.

2) If your service and data access beans(like you mentioned ContactDAO, UserEntityDAO etc.,) for some reason are in dispatcher-servlet.xml, then you mentioned it in two places

```
    a) <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml
                    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
       </context-param>

     This is fine.

    b) In dispatcher servlet:
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

    This becomes the sibling of JerseyServlet1 which will not have any visibility into it and its beans. So remove this from dispatcher-servlet <init-param>
```